# Что означают time и state в логе MySQL?

Tags: запрос, логирование, mysql

Помогите с объяснением логов MySQL запросов.

[image]

Пожалуйста, скажите, пожалуйста, что означают тут time и state? time скорее сколько выполняется запрос или через сколько выполнится запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time`

> The time in seconds that the thread has been in its current state.
>
> Время в секундах, в течение которого поток находится в текущем сотоянии

`State`

> An action, event, or state that indicates what the thread is doing.
>
> Действие, событие или состотяние, отображающее что делает поток

[8.10. Examining Thread Information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/thread-information.html)